# Strip content from URL and build a string with Javascript and Regex

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I would like to strip the item name from a URL using Javascript. Not sure whether Regex is the way to go with this, as I need to capitalize the item name after it is extracted.

BEFORE
`https://www.sportsdirect.com/karrimor-lifestyle-fleece-mens-443326?colcode=44332603`

AFTER
`"Karrimor Lifestyle Fleece Mens 443226"`

So anything between the / after the URL and before the ? character and stripping out any - characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```js
var result = 'https://www.sportsdirect.com/karrimor-lifestyle-fleece-mens-443326?colcode=44332603'
  .replace(/(.*\/|\?.*)/g, '')
  .split(/\W/)
  .map(function(w) {
    return w[0].toUpperCase() + w.substr(1);
  })
  .join(' ');
  
console.log(result);
```

To give some explanation of what the snippet does (line by line):

1. `replace(/(.*\/|\?.*)/g, '')` remove unwanted parts of URL via RegEx (but keep the path string as it is, with hyphens etc.)
2. `split(/\W/)` split into parts along non-word characters (produces array)
3. `map(function(w) {...` transform every array element...
4. `return w[0].toUpperCase() + w.substr(1);` ... to have the first "letter" uppercased.
5. `.join(' ');` ... and join the elements to a string again, delimited by a whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Use `new URL(url).pathname.substring(1)` to get the [pathname](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/pathname) from your url. Then **split** it by `-`, **map** it to **uppercase** only the first characters of every word and finally **join** it back. Hope this is what you want :)

```js
var url = 'https://www.sportsdirect.com/karrimor-lifestyle-fleece-mens-443326?colcode=44332603';
var expected_part = new URL(url).pathname.substring(1); // to ignore 1st character
var expected_result = expected_part.toLowerCase()
  .split('-')
  .map((s) => s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1))
  .join(' ');
console.log(expected_result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it:

```
function capitalizeFirstLetter(string) {
    return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}
var input = "https://www.sportsdirect.com/karrimor-lifestyle-fleece-mens-443326?colcode=44332603";
input = input.substring(0, input.indexOf("?"));
input = input.substring(input.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
input = input.split("-").map(x => capitalizeFirstLetter(x)).join(" ");
```

`capitalizeFirstLetter` was taken from [How do I make the first letter of a string uppercase in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/how-do-i-make-the-first-letter-of-a-string-uppercase-in-javascript)